# If $n$ and $p$ are coprime how it will be true for some $x$ and $y$. $Nx+ py = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $n$ and $p$ are coprime how it will be true for some $x$ and $y$.
$Nx+ py = 1$

Answer (score -2):

The **Bezout's Lemma** tells you the basis for this sort of equations, called *diophantine*.

**Bezout's Lemma**

Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero integers and $d$ their *greatest common divisor*. Then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $$ax+by=d$$

So, in this particular case, $d=1$ and you have the thesis.